# Civ 5 mod compatibility

Tags: civilization-5, mods

In the vanilla version of Civ 5 (the mac version), is it possible to add new civilizations as a mod? Because I added [this](http://forums.civfanatics.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=17156) mod and when I enable it, no new civ shows up when I go to select them. I'm not going back to the main menu after I enable the mods, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46755/how-can-i-enable-civ-5-mods-on-mac-os-x)? I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but they seem similar to me.

Comment: @Fluttershy yea I got the mod menu to show up and the mods to show up in the menu, the problem is when I enable them they have no effect.

Comment: The mod hasn't been updated for two years. It's possible it's no longer compatible with the current version.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [How to get the Steam Workshop to work with "Civilization 5" for a Mac?][http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75167/how-to-get-the-steam-workshop-to-work-with-civilization-v-for-a-mac], in which it is said that enabling the mods button doesn't make Civ 5 modding compatible with OSX.