# How can I enable Civ 5 Mods button on Mac OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

EDIT: Figured it out. Looks like in the other thread, the updated G&K directions were incorrect (at least for me). I simply followed the original directions and found the Controls.ModsButton:SetHide(true) and fixed it, per original instructions. Sorry for the duplicate! Thanks for all the help!

I looked at this link first: [How can I enable Civ 5 mods on Mac OS X?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46755/how-can-i-enable-civ-5-mods-on-mac-os-x)

But I got stuck where it says Front End/Mainmenu.lua. Mine is a .xml file (not sure if that matters). Anyway, I opened it up using Text Editor on Mac, but couldn't find the "Controls.ModsButton:SetHide( true );" to change it. So now I am stuck. This is what it says instead:

```
  <GridButton Anchor="C,T" ID="ModsButton"          Size="320,45"    Style="ZoomButton" String="TXT_KEY_MODS" >
    <ShowOnMouseOver>
      <AlphaAnim Anchor="L,T" Size="320,48" Pause="0" Cycle="Bounce" Speed="1" AlphaStart="1.5" AlphaEnd="1">
        <Grid   Size="320,48" Offset="0,-2" Padding="0,0" Style="Grid9FrameTurnsHL" />
      </AlphaAnim>
      <AlphaAnim Anchor="L,T" Size="320,48" Pause="0" Cycle="Once" Speed="1" AlphaStart=".2" AlphaEnd="0">
        <Image Anchor="R,C" Offset="0,0" AnchorSide="O.I" Texture="Assets/UI/Art/WorldView/WindowGlowRight.dds" Size="42,86" />
        <Image Anchor="L,C" Offset="0,0" AnchorSide="O.I" Texture="Assets/UI/Art/WorldView/WindowGlowLeft.dds" Size="42,86" />
      </AlphaAnim>

    </ShowOnMouseOver>
    <Image Anchor="C,T" AnchorSide="I.O" Offset="0,0" Texture="bar300x2.dds" Size="300.1" />
  </GridButton>
```

If you want the whole text, I can post it. But nothing that I saw suggested a "hide mods button" so I'm not sure what to do next. I have Gods & Kings as well. Help!

Comment: There are several Mainmenu.lua files being referenced in the answers of that question.  Are you sure you're looking at the right one?

Comment: @fbueckert I followed this direction from the other Question:

Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/common/sid meier civilization v/Civilization V : Gods & Kings/Contents/Home/assets/DLC/Expansion/UI/FrontEnd/MainMenu.lua

But that last MainMenu.lua is MainMenu.xml in mine. There IS a MainMenu.lua, but it is under assets/UI/FrontEnd, which is not the directory to follow if you have G&K (which I do), according to Private Pansy.

Comment: They might have changed it again.  Do you have Brave New world as well?  It might be worthwhile to update the existing answers on the other question.

Comment: I dont see how this is a duplicate question. The other thread that this is supposedly a duplicate of did not help me figure out my problem, which is why I am asking again. Will someone please help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, @Nav, this question's already been asked.  Arqade doesn't allow the same questions, that's why we have duplicates.  I'm trying to help you figure out what the problem might be.  Do you have Brave New World, along with Gods & Kings?  Perhaps there's a different file you need to modify.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm sorry, I'm brand new to this site. I do have G&K but not BNW (I bought the Gold edition, so I don't believe it comes with BNW). Like I said, I followed the method for G&K in the other thread, but I did not find the MainMenu.lua under the Civ5Gods&Kings/Contents/Home/assets/DLC/expansion/UI/frontend; I found MainMenu.xlm instead...I did however find MainMenu.lua but it was under Civ5G&K/contents/home/assets/UI/Frontend/MainMenu.lua, which is not where to go if you have G&K (according to the other thread instructions). 

Thank you for helping me, I really do appreciate it!